# How do I sum string arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a simulated test that is ready to be graded.  My main module request user input  of 20 multiple choice answers (A,B,C,D).  I am using  a for loop to populate both arrays.  I next have an If .equals statements that compares the two arrays for correct answer and in correct answer. `

My current out put is:

The correct answer to question 16 is: C
Your answer to question 16 is: C
Question 16 is correct

The correct answer to question 17 is: C
Your answer to question 17 is: A
Question 17 is incorrect

Next

I am attempting to simulate an out put of:

You passed the exam with a grade of 90%.  Congratulations!

Number of correct answers: 18
Number of incorrect answers: 2

Here is the portion of code I am working on

int arraySize;

```
    arraySize = 20;
    
    // Declare and assign the variables to create the parallel array
    int count;
    
  
    // Access the contents of both arrays
    for (count = 0; count <= arraySize - 1; count++) {
        System.out.println();
        // Message to diplay the Answerkey and testAnswer
        System.out.println("The correct answer to question " + (count + 1) + " is: " + answerKeyArray[count]);
        System.out.println("Your answer to question " + (count + 1) + " is: " + testAnswers[count]);
        
        // Find the correct and incorrect answers
        if (answerKeyArray[count].equals(testAnswers[count])) {
            
            // Message to display the answer is correct
            
            System.out.println("Question " + (count + 1) + " is correct ");
            
        } else {
            
            // Message to display the answer is incorrect
            System.out.println("Question " + (count + 1) + " is incorrect ");
```

Comment: Hint: Add a counter outside your `for` loop, and just increase it by one for every correct question.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have just learned about an accumulator.  Are you referring to this? If not this is where I am lost as this is the only way so far that I have learned to calculate the total (int) . This is my first attempting string value as well working with arrays

Comment: Thank you again for your response it was Helpful and I was able to make my corrections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a counter variable **inside** the for loop, which would make it a **local** variable, and it would be voided after it goes outside the for loop. Below is an example

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
int correctCounter = 0;
int incorrectCounter = 0;
if(PretendThisIsAConditional){
counter++;
}
else{
incorrectCounter++;
System.out.println("Number of correct answers: " + correctCounter + "Number of incorrect answers: " + incorrectCounter);
}
```

If you have the number correct inside a string for whatever reason you can do

```
int numCorrect = Integer.parseInt(String);
```

Comment: Thank you again for your response . I returned to thank the initial response for the alternate thought.  I figured out how to initiate the counter my examples are similar to yours.   int correct = 0 and int incorrect = 0 .   I did not use the integer.parseInt();      my output statement now is as follows The correct answer to question 19 is: D
Your answer to question 19 is: A
Question 19 is incorrect 

The correct answer to question 20 is: A
Your answer to question 20 is: B
Question 20 is incorrect 

 You answers 15 correctly 
 You answers 5 incorrectly